# Programming language for opengl screenshot software

Tags: python, perl, opengl

I need to develop a multiplatform software that takes screenshots from opengl games without affecting the game in performance, it will run in the background and will add a watermark to my screenshots.

What language should i use? I thought of Perl / Python.
Anyone can point me out something to start?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be very difficult to make it truly multiplatform. Since you (probably) can't access the game's runtime directly, how are you going to get a screenshot? Ask the OS for help? That would probably work but how you do that could vary widely from one platform to another.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest C++. That way you can use OpenGL and DirectX libraries and API calls natively. Libraries that provide such functionality to other languages typically abstract the good stuff away from reach.

Comment: I was thinking of Java using JOGL : com.sun.opengl.util.Screenshot.

Comment: I've no experience with Java so I can't help you there, although that method will probably dump the screenbuffer of the current application render target, not an arbitrary one.

Answer (score 0):

The language you know best that has some sort of OpenGL Bindings.

My personal preference for such kind of applications is C, C++ or (if available) C# but it's a simple matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to add a watermark right when you take the screenshot? It would be a lot easier to simply add the watermark later to the static image, as many applications can do this (e.g. Photoshop).

Comment: the watermak is going to be added after being saved and has to be done  from programming code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about modifying [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) for your purpose? It is written in Perl.